# Favouriting things in a database - most efficient method of keeping track?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a forum-like webapp where I'd like to allow users to favourite an item so that they can keep track of it, and also so that others can see how many times an item's been favourited.

The problem is, I'm unsure on the best practices for databases, which includes this situation.

I have two ideas in my head on how to do this:

1. Add an extra column to the user table and store things like so: "|2|5|73|"
2. Add an extra table with at least two columns, one for referencing an item, the other for referencing a user.

I feel uncomfortable about going for the second method as it involves an extra table, and potentially more queries would be required. Perhaps these beliefs aren't an issue, as I have little understanding of databases beyond simply working with table layouts and basic queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second method, commonly called a [junction or join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), is fairly standard practice and is going to be far more efficient than adding a column like the one you describe to the user table. Through the magic of `JOIN`s you won't be making any extra queries.

Since it sounds like your app is starting to get a little complex, I highly recommend picking up a MySQL database book at your local library or book store (check for reviews on Amazon to find a good one) and expanding your knowledge.

Comment: Alright, I do that, thanks. Although I'm already familiar with basic query syntax, so I am assuming you're recommending a book for another reason?

Comment: Well, using relational databases effectively means much more than just knowing basic query syntax. It's just a good idea to expand your knowledge of normalization, relational algebra, and so on, especially if you intend to do more of this kind of thing in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd have +1-ed the otherresponse but I'm too much of a newb apparently.  But yes, I recommend a join table for this type of thing.